# How to allow each user access his / her details of SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

I have around 200 users data in my database. I have generated reports for each user containing charts and tables etc. I want to allow each user to access his or her data using URI from our mobile app. Since the users are logged in the app I dont want to relogin them on the web page.

At the moment I think i will upload the SSRS reports to the webserver and using URI users can click a link in the app to direct to their webpage and see their data.

I dont have any idea of how to achieve it. Can you please give me suggesstion on how to achieve it in the best possible way. Any links, support etc will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble understanding your question. Are all of these users looking at a similar report, just different data? If so, there is a UserID built in field in SSRS, and you could use that as a hidden parameter to pass to your query.

Comment: Yes, For example a report will show their in/out for the last three months. Each user will have separate data. I want to create a dashboard (their own index/home page) where user can interact to see his last week data or last month or year etc.

Comment: As long as you can use the windows credentials that get passed to SSRS as the filter for the report I would recommend using the built-in global `User!UserID` instead of trying to pass it as a parameter to the report in the URI. Using the URI method could allow users to access data that isn't theirs by simply changing the URI. See more about SSRS built-in globals here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd255216.aspx